# Chart bar not property sizing when scalar axis's interval set to 1

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

When I create a Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services 2012 bar chart with the horizontal axis type set to scalar and the interval set to 1, the rendered bar size does not match the axis label size.

In the example below, a value of 1 should be displayed for 9/1/12 and a value of 52 should be displayed for 9/5/12. However, the bars span too wide. Each spans three date labels instead of just one.

How do I limit the chart's bars so that they are the proper width?

Thank you!

[image: Bar chart demonstraighting problem]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem, I changed the MaxPixelPointWidth to a value, in my case 15, and that fixed my problem.

```
(Chart Series properties=>CustomAttributes=>MaxPixelPointWidth) //Mari
```

Comment: Thanks for this tip, @Mari! Setting the MaxPixelPointWidth works *if* the desired bar width can be predicted in advance (e.g. if the number of items on the x-axis is fixed). Sometimes the number of bars is dynamic, in which case manually setting the bar max width doesn't work. Unfortunately, I have yet to find a way to work around this bug. :-( It appears that your solution is the best solution to this problem.

Comment: I have other solution - simulate 0 value for missed, but MaxPixel PointWidth is much better solution